# FindByIndexNameSessionRepository “RedisConnectionFactory is required” configuration error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis, spring-session

Implementing the logic of limiting active sessions for each user (number of possible sessions stored in the database, sessions in Redis), I came across the problem of configuring `FindByIndexNameSessionRepository`.

Due to the fact that I am injecting `FindByIndexNameSessionRepository` spring starts to configure the bean in the [RedisHttpSessionConfiguration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/api/org/springframework/session/data/redis/config/annotation/web/http/RedisHttpSessionConfiguration.html) class, and the fields are not injected into the class via setters.

As a result, I get the error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: RedisConnectionFactory is required
at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:73) ~[spring-core-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisAccessor.afterPropertiesSet(RedisAccessor.java:38) ~[spring-data-redis-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.afterPropertiesSet(RedisTemplate.java:127) ~[spring-data-redis-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.RedisHttpSessionConfiguration.createRedisTemplate(RedisHttpSessionConfiguration.java:291) ~[spring-session-data-redis-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.RedisHttpSessionConfiguration.sessionRepository(RedisHttpSessionConfiguration.java:120) ~[spring-session-data-redis-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
```

Config code:

```
@EnableRedisHttpSession
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CustomConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private final FindByIndexNameSessionRepository sessionRepository;    
    // ....

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**")
                .authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .and()
            // ....
            .sessionManagement()
                .sessionAuthenticationStrategy(new CustomAuthenticationStrategy(sessionRegistry(), sessionsLimitRepository));
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringSessionBackedSessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {
        return new SpringSessionBackedSessionRegistry(sessionRepository);
    }

    @Bean
    public LettuceConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory() {
        return new LettuceConnectionFactory(new RedisStandaloneConfiguration("server", 6379));
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpSessionEventPublisher httpSessionEventPublisher() {
        return new HttpSessionEventPublisher();
   }

}
```

pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-session-data-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-session-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- .... -->
</dependencies>
```

If you remove\comment out the places where `FindByIndexNameSessionRepository` is used, then the [RedisHttpSessionConfiguration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/api/org/springframework/session/data/redis/config/annotation/web/http/RedisHttpSessionConfiguration.html) setters are called by the "guts" of the spring when the `springSessionRepositoryFilter` bean is created.

If I understood correctly, then I accidentally broke the order of configuring the beans. In attempts to fix it, I tried @DependsOn, @Lazy and various frauds with moving bins to different classes of configs, changing the order of loading configs, and so on.

UPD: Add bean `httpSessionEventPublisher` and pom.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem was that spring-boot had already configured most of the bins for me.

To resolve this problem, you must remove `@EnableRedisHttpSession` (`@EnableWebSecurity` can also be deleted), beans `redisConnectionFactory` and `httpSessionEventPublisher`, and optionally you can remove the unnecessary dependency `spring-session-core`

Actual config code:

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CustomConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final FindByIndexNameSessionRepository<? extends Session> sessionRepository;

    // ....

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**")
                .authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .and()
            // ....
            .sessionManagement()
                .sessionAuthenticationStrategy(new CustomAuthenticationStrategy(sessionRegistry(), sessionsLimitRepository));
}

    @Bean
    public SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {
        return new SpringSessionBackedSessionRegistry<>(sessionRepository);
    }

}
```

Actual pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-session-data-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- .... -->
</dependencies>
```